# Datatables Single Column Filter particialy

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-4

Im using datatables and this script to show table on my page. 
http://jsfiddle.net/8fLagfyp/19/

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>17012</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>16012</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Im trying to create a filter for the first column. But i would like to be able to filter it by particialy value. In this case I have '16012' and '17012', I would like to have just '16' & '17'  in the filter. I would be able to setup those values manually if its not possible to do it automatically. By default it should show highest value (or set it manually), and be able to choose show All.

thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried any scripts for this yourself? We normally ask that you post a specific question after you have made an attempt at the task. Otherwise you're pretty much asking someone else to write the code for you.

Comment: I did. i have that script in jsfiddle. I was not able to find solution to filter just one column or to subtract column`s text for that filter.